# WebLogic Managed server start taking more time after application deployment

Tags: memory, weblogic, g1gc

i have deployed flexcube application, after the deployment my managed server startup is taking almost 50 min but still it's in starting position, i have allocated -xms16g -xmx16g g1gc, could someone help me to identify the issue, i have attached the jmap heap output

```
 Attaching to process ID 6918, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.261-b12

using thread-local object allocation.
Garbage-First (G1) GC with 4 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 70
   MaxHeapSize              = 17179869184 (16384.0MB)
   NewSize                  = 1363144 (1.2999954223632812MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 10301210624 (9824.0MB)
   OldSize                  = 5452592 (5.1999969482421875MB)
   NewRatio                 = 2
   SurvivorRatio            = 8
   MetaspaceSize            = 21807104 (20.796875MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 8388608 (8.0MB)

Heap Usage:
G1 Heap:
   regions  = 2048
   capacity = 17179869184 (16384.0MB)
   used     = 2976539984 (2838.6497344970703MB)
   free     = 14203329200 (13545.35026550293MB)
   17.32574300840497% used
G1 Young Generation:
Eden Space:
   regions  = 52
   capacity = 855638016 (816.0MB)
   used     = 436207616 (416.0MB)
   free     = 419430400 (400.0MB)
   50.98039215686274% used
Survivor Space:
   regions  = 6
   capacity = 50331648 (48.0MB)
   used     = 50331648 (48.0MB)
   free     = 0 (0.0MB)
   100.0% used
G1 Old Generation:
   regions  = 298
   capacity = 16273899520 (15520.0MB)
   used     = 2490000720 (2374.6497344970703MB)
   free     = 13783898800 (13145.35026550293MB)
   15.300578186192464% used

83978 interned Strings occupying 10729592 bytes.
```

Comment: The first action is to take several thread dumps during server startup (using jstack for instance) and see where deployment thread is working on.

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel, will do the same